# To extract the area and city of the properties based on number of flats

Tags: html, select

I am trying to automate the following scenario by selenium java:

1. Go to https://appaswamy.com/residential/
2. Select All from dropdown box
3. Extract the area and city of the properties which has more than 100 flats and more than 3 blocks.
4. Print the area and city in the eclipse console.

I tried with the following code:

```
WebElement resi= driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Residential"));
        resi.click();
        
        WebElement all= driver.findElement(By.id("a_filter_categ"));
        all.click();
        
        WebElement complete= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[contains(text(),'All')]"));
        complete.click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        List<WebElement> layer = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"listing_ajax_container\"]"));
        for(WebElement l : layer)
        {
            l.click();
            //WebElement description= driver.findElements(By.partialLinkText('https://']"));
            //description.click();
            driver.navigate().back();
        }
```